# Specify the host as simply <ad name>@<domain> to load balance between the AD servers,e.g. ad.domain.com

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

Could someone please explain me what do they refer with the following sentence:

> If you are using Microsoft's DNS in conjunction with Active Directory, you can also specify the host as simply (ad name)@(domain) to load balance between the AD servers,e.g. ad.domain.com.

[Using OTRS with Active Directory as a source for agents](http://wiki.otterhub.org/index.php?title=Using_OTRS_with_Active_Directory_as_a_source_for_agents)

I've tried to google it but no luck or maybe my AD knowledge isn't enough.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly simple and should be well supported if your environment is as they describe. I do think there's a mistake in their documentation though, their talk of *ad name@domain* is unhelpful. You bind to AD /  domain controllers using the format I describe below. You'd identify users within AD (e.g. specifying a user to connect with to carry out your LDAP query) using the format *user@ad.example.com*

When carrying out LDAP queries, rather than binding to a specific Active Directory server, it's possible to bind to the address of the AD domain itself.

This should load-balance queries as they say, as well as providing an element of resilience in the OTRS service if you have an AD server offline for maintenance (e.g. it will only connect to available servers).

For example, lets say you have a domain, *ad.example.com* with two domain controllers, *dc1.ad.example.com* and *dc2.ad.example.com*. You can connect directly to either domain controller with your LDAP bind statement, e.g. you can connect to *dc1.ad.example.com*. It should also be possible to bind to *ad.example.com* rather than to a specific server.

Comment: Thank you Rob. Now I get it! Thank you for your help and have a great day :)